# Using sub functions warning in perl

Tags: perl

What is the difference between `sub SampleFunc() { ... }` and `sub SampleFunc { ... }`

Since if I am using `()` parenthesis I am getting warning while Compilation `perl -wc Testing`. if I am not using `()` parenthesis in `sub SampleFunc` sure I am not getting warning message.

Eg:

```
 $sampleout = cleartex($sampleinput);
```

Error Message:

```
 main::cleartex() called too early to check prototype at Sample.pl line xxx.
```

Could you please someone explain on this one. If I removed `()` then might be received any major difference in the output?

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you declare a subroutine with parenthesis you are defining a perl prototype. This is *usually* not something you want to be doing, because perl prototypes aren't the kind you'd recognise from other languages.

[perldoc prototype](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)

Mostly, you just shouldn't use them in normal practice - the uses/reasons for them are pretty niche, and are mostly when you're trying to re-implement certain built in functions in different ways.

Just lose the prototype, and carry on with your day, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Moreover, the prototype in `sub cleartex()` is declaring that the subroutine takes *no parameters*, which is clearly not what the OP wants.